# How to get an NSLayoutAnchor from a switch case?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'd like to do something like:

```
public enum LayoutEdge
{
    case top
    case right
    ...
}

func anchorForLayoutEdge(_ edge : LayoutEdge) -> NSLayoutAnchor {
    switch edge
    {
    case .top:      return topAnchor
    case .right:    return rightAnchor
    ... 
    }
}

public func constrain_edge(_ edge : LayoutEdge,
                           toEdge : LayoutEdge,
                           view : UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint{
    let a1 = anchorForLayoutEdge(edge)
    let a2 = anchorForLayoutEdge(toEdge)
    return a1.constraint(equalTo: a2))
}
```

But this does not compile. It fails in anchorForLayoutEdge. Xcode suggests changing the return type to NSLayoutAnchor which seems wrong. How can I make it so that it returns the correct `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` or `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` depending on the edge specified?

Answer (score 1):

Swift needs to be able to determine the types at compile-time but you try to return either
`NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>` or `NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>` objects depending on
the passed `edge` parameter.

What you *could* do is is split up your edges into edges related to x-axis and y-axis:

```
extension UIView
{
    public enum XLayoutEdge {
        case right
        // ...
    }

    public enum YLayoutEdge {
        case top
        // ...
    }

    func anchor(for edge: XLayoutEdge) -> NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor> {
        switch edge
        {
        case .right: return rightAnchor
        // ...
        }
    }

    func anchor(for edge: YLayoutEdge) -> NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor> {
        switch edge
        {
        case .top: return topAnchor
        // ...
        }
    }

    public func constrain(edge edge1: XLayoutEdge, to edge2: XLayoutEdge, of view: UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return anchor(for: edge1).constraint(equalTo: view.anchor(for: edge2))
    }

    public func constrain(edge edge1: YLayoutEdge, to edge2: YLayoutEdge, of view: UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return anchor(for: edge1).constraint(equalTo: view.anchor(for: edge2))
    }

    func useEdges(view: UIView)
    {
        _ = constrain(edge: .right, to: .right, of: view)
        _ = constrain(edge: .top, to: .top, of: view)
    }
}
```

It would get even worse because you would have to consider `NSLayoutDimension`, too.  You could play around with generics
but you'd probably end up replicating in some way what Apple has already put in place for you :).

That's why I think you are working against the system here. Taking a step back, why not work with anchors directly?

```
extension UIView
{
    func useAnchors(view: UIView)
    {
        _ = rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)
        _ = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    }
}
```

If you want to write your own convenience functions you could do it like this:

```
extension UIView
{
    public func constrain<T>(_ anchor1: NSLayoutAnchor<T>, to anchor2: NSLayoutAnchor<T>) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return anchor1.constraint(equalTo: anchor2)
    }

    func useYourOwnFunctions(view: UIView)
    {
        _ = constrain(rightAnchor, to: view.rightAnchor)
        _ = constrain(topAnchor, to: view.bottomAnchor)
    }
}
```